# How to get elements between tags with XPATH

Tags: xpath, xpath-2.0, domxpath

I need to get each subtitle of an article and its text. Since each subheading is inside , and I need to get everything between the first  and the second. And then I will do between the second and third until I finish.

The structure is similar to this:

```
<article>
<p> introducion </p>

<h3>1. Subtitle </h3>
<p> text text </p>
<div> <p>other text</p> </div>

<h3>2. Subtitle </h3>
<p> text text </p>
<div> <p>other text</p> </div>

<h3>3. Subtitle </h3>
<p> text text </p>
<div> <p>other text</p> </div>

</article>
```

Currently I can get to the first subtitle like this: `//h3[1]`

But how can I get everything between the first  and the second  ???

Comment: [tag:domxpath] seems to support XPath-1.0 only.

Answer (score 1):

This XPath expression gets nodes between `//h3[1]` and `//h3[2]` inclusive

```
//article/*[position()>= count(//h3[1]/preceding-sibling::*)+1 and position()<= count(//h3[2]/preceding-sibling::*)+1]
```

Result on browser console

```
$x('//article/*[position()>= count(//h3[1]/preceding-sibling::*)+1 and position()<= count(//h3[2]/preceding-sibling::*)+1]')
Array(4) [ h3, p, div, h3]
0: <h3>​
1: <p>​
2: <div>​
3: <h3>
length: 4
```